# I bought a sword, now what?

Tags: candy-box-2

I bought a sword in Candy Box two. I expected to be able to clear the guy's cellar of rats, but I can't seem to start the quest, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you buy something new, you must go to your inventory and equip it. Once you've bought the sword you should see a new `INVENTORY` tab at the top.